# Documents are always locked in SharePoint

Tags: check-out, graph-api

I am trying to use Graph API to check if a document is locked or not. There does not seem to be any special method in the Graph API to check for file locks so I am trying to come up with my own. This is what I have made:

```
public bool IsDriveItemLocked(string driveId, string driveItemId)
{
    try
    {
        Task.Run(() => graphClient.Drives[driveId].Items[driveItemId].Checkout.PostAsync()).Wait();
        var requestBody = new Microsoft.Graph.Drives.Item.Items.Item.Checkin.CheckinPostRequestBody
        {
            Comment = "Checking if item is locked from app.",
        };
        Task.Run(() => graphClient.Drives[driveId].Items[driveItemId].Checkin.PostAsync(requestBody)).Wait();
        return false;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The idea is that if checking out the document throws an error then it must be locked. And indeed it does throw a 423 error but the problem is that EVERY document throws this error. No matter if it was just created and has been closed in the browser or not.

Is there a way to do this in a better way or does someone know why every single document throws 423 error when trying to checkout?